# Extract Json without property names in Python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to extract location data from a json API service. This is how far i got:

```
>>> import json
>>> import urllib
>>> from urllib import urlopen
>>> url = urlopen('THE API URL').read()
>>> print url
[["244630489","53.099040","6.040552","0","0","99","2016-07-26T15:28:59"]]
>>> result = json.loads(url)
>>> print result
[[u'244630489', u'53.099040', u'6.040552', u'0', u'0', u'99', u'2016-07-26T15:28:59']]
```

Now i would like to extract the second en thirth value. I cant figure out how to do it using json.loads, because there are no property names.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting an array represented as a list of list, do the following:

```
import json
import urllib
from urllib import urlopen
url = urlopen('THE API URL').read()
print url
print url[0][1:3]
```

Which will print:

```
['53.099040', '6.040552']
```

Or similarly with json:

```
result = json.loads(url)
print result[0][1:3]
```

Which will print:

```
[u'53.099040', u'6.040552']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a part of `result`, you would do

```
part = result[0][1:3]
```

or

```
a=result[0][1]
b=result[0][2]
```

as `result`is a nested list in your case